# Check whether a path is valid in Python

Tags: python

Is there any easy way to check whether a path is valid? The file doesn't have to exist now, I'm wondering if it could exist.

my current version is this:

```
try:
  f = open(path)
except:
  <path invalid>
```

I'm considering simply checking whether the path contains any of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words) characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check whether a path is valid in Python without creating a file at the path's target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532499/check-whether-a-path-is-valid-in-python-without-creating-a-file-at-the-paths-ta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempting it first is the best way, I recommend doing that.

```
try:
    open(filename, 'w')
except OSError:
    # handle error here
```

I believe you'll get OSError, catch that explicitly, and test on the platform you're using this on.

Comment: +1 and just for reference it's `IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: ...`

Comment: **Problematic answer.** If `filename` does _not_ exist, this solution silently creates it as a 0-byte file. (_That's probably bad._) If `filename` is an existing file, this solution silently truncates it to a 0-byte file. (_That's definitely bad._) If `filename` is an existing directory, this solution raises an exception that will need to be differentiated from the desired `[Errno 22]` `IOError` exception described by [bernie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42346/bernie) above. (_That's at least annoying._) In short, you probably do _not_ want to try this.

Answer (score 7):

You can also try the below:

```
import os  
if not os.path.exists(file_path):
    print "Path of the file is Invalid"
```

Comment: This just reports whether a file exists.  The question specifically asks about whether a path is *valid*, not whether it exists.

Comment: If the file exists, then its a valid path naturaully and it does exist

Comment: Is not really a formal fallacy but a problem of definition. A path is valid when it can exist, i.e. a path that exist or that does not necessarily exist, but can be created if required.

Comment: According to 3.5.7 documentation:  

   "Return True if path refers to an existing path or an open file descriptor."  

This would solve the question as asked.


https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists

Comment: To echo aquavitae. I'm accepting user input. I want to check that the path is valid (the OP's question). Path "/Users/billybob/config.txt" is valid whether it exists or not. Path "£@/somewhere**spilled_coffee_on_the_keyboard" is not valid, and never could be.

Comment: OP: "The file doesn't have to exist now, I'm wondering if it could exist.". So this test would claim that r"D:\Windows" was invalid, when what it is actually reacting to is merely that the folder does not exist.

Comment: @Richard `£@/somewhere**spilled_coffee_on_the_keyboard` is a perfectly valid pathname, at least on non-Windows (filesystems).

Answer (score 1):

From python 3.4, to check if path is valid, you can also use `pathlib` module to do this:

```py
from pathlib import Path

try:
    Path(file_path).resolve()
    exist = True
except (OSError, RuntimeError):
    exist = False
```

Comment: Just be aware that this will return "True" for a whole bunch of invalid paths on every system, you REALLY have to go out of your way to give this something it will reject, like injecting null bytes into the filename.

Comment: I experimented and found that in Python 3.9.x, a `ValueError` is raised when a null character is present, so that `except` statement is incomplete. Also, I have been unable to come up with any other way to get a failure, but that is because there are so ridiculously few limitations on what is a valid Posix path.