# Determine if string could be a valid directory or file in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to check if `String` is valid as a local path in **Dart**, (It **doesn't** matter whether the path exists or not), I want to check if the `String` is valid to be used as a local path or not.

similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17558181/7222115) with **Python**

Comment: In general, whether a path is valid depends on the file system.  As there are many possible file systems (even for a single platform), the only real way to tell if a path would be valid is to actually try using it.

Answer (score 1):

**File**

```
Async
    File("yourfile").exists()

sync
    File("/sdcard/").existsSync()
```

**Directory**

```
  Directory("your directory").exists()
  Directory("/sdcard/").existsSync()
```

use with try catch

Both cases you need android permission to access the file
otherwise you will get a file or directory or path not exist exception. if already file exist