# How does the code example in the python os module documentation create a security hole?

Tags: python, file-access, python-os

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.access) for the `os` module makes the following assertion:

---

Note

Using access() to check if a user is authorized to e.g. open a file before actually doing so using open() creates a security hole, because the user might exploit the short time interval between checking and opening the file to manipulate it. It’s preferable to use [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) techniques. For example:

```
if os.access("myfile", os.R_OK):
    with open("myfile") as fp:
    return fp.read()
return "some default data"`
```

is better written as:

```
try:
    fp = open("myfile")
except PermissionError:
    return "some default data"
else:
    with fp:
        return fp.read()
```

---

I don't understand how a user "might exploit" the interval.  If `open` was going to raise an exception, I'm not sure how `os.access` would prevent that exception from being raised.  Likewise, if the user manipulate the file somehow, why not perform the file manipulation prior to the EAFP version's `open` command?

I do understand that the second version may be more robust, since `os.access` may fail to correctly recognize a condition that could raise a `PermissionError`, but I don't see how the [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl) version is less *secure*.  Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the `access`-using code is unsafe, the second code snippet doesn't solve the security issues. These docs should be changed.

The purpose of `os.access` is to test whether the real user id has permission to access a file when the real and effective user ids are different. The danger with the `os.access` snippet is that the user could place a file `access` returns `True` for in the location being tested, then swap it out for a file `access` would have returned `False` for, bypassing the check. Since `open` uses the effective user id, the `open` call can still work, bypassing the `access` check.

The second snippet doesn't solve this problem. Now the user doesn't even need to go through the switcheroo. No part of the second snippet checks the real user id.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check.  Do you know if there is a recommended way (in python) to mitigate this risk?  (Or is it as seemingly hopeless as [validating file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532499/)?)

Comment: @K.Nielson: I'm not sure. It mostly matters with setuid scripts, which are [kind of a security/compatibility mess already](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts/2910#2910), and I'm not sure what the best practices are for such scripts even when the OS supports them. I think you're probably supposed to use [`os.seteuid`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.seteuid) to temporarily set the effective user id to the real user id while opening and reading the file, then set it back afterwards. I don't know if that's fully secure, though.