# Determine if a path is valid in a class constructor

Tags: python-3.x, path, directory

Without violating the guideline that a [constructor should do work](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/305464/legitimate-real-work-in-a-constructor?noredirect=1&lq=1), I need to determine if the provided string (`destination_directory`) is a valid path before assigning it in the constructor.

It doesn't have to exist, but the provide string must be a valid one, i.e. no invalid symbols, or illegal characters. My project will run on Windows only, not Linux.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532499/check-whether-a-path-is-valid-in-python-without-creating-a-file-at-the-paths-ta) page, but the answers seem to try and open the directory to test if the provided string is valid.

I also tried `os.path.isabs(path)`but it doesn't provide the results I require. For example, it says that `T:\\\\Pictures` is a absolute path, while that may be true, the `\\\\` should mean the path is invalid.

Is there a clean, perhaps one line way of achieving what I want?

```
def __init__(self, destination_directory: str)
    self._validate_path(path=destination_directory)
    self.destination_directory = destination_directory

def _validate_path(self, path)
    # code to validate path should go here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now a few things about a path, it contains at least a drive letter and subdirectories.

We also have rules about [what symbols are not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file) allowed in directories. We also know that a drive letter contains a single character.

Instead of allowing users of our class to pass in a full path, we break it down and only allow valid strings for directories names and one letter for the drive. When everything is validated, we can use the `os` module to build our path.

Here is how I would structure my `Folder` class:

```
class Folder:

    def __init__(self, *subdirectories, root_drive):
        self._validate_drive_letter(letter = root_drive)
        self._validate_path(path=subdirectories)

        self._root_drive = root_drive
        self._subdirectories = subdirectories

    def _validate_drive_letter(self, letter):
        if not letter or len(letter) > 2 or not letter.isalpha():
            raise ValueError("Drive letter is invalid")

    def _validate_path(self, path):
        self._forbidden_characters = ["<", ">", ":", "/", '"', "|", "?", "*", '\\']
        for character in path:
            for item in character:
                if item in self._forbidden_characters:
                    raise ValueError("Directory cannot contain invalid characters")

    def construct_full_path(self) -> str:
        # use the os module and constructor parameters to build a valid path

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Drive Letter: {self._root_drive} Subdirectories: {self._subdirectories}"
```

**Main:**

```
def main():

    try:

        portable_drive = Folder("Pictures", "Landscape", root_drive="R") # Valid
        # Using the construct_full_path() function, the returned string would be:
        # R:\Pictures\Landscape
        # Notice the user doesn't provide the : or the \, the class will do it.

        vacation_pictures = Folder("Vac??tion", root_drive="T") # Will raise ValueError
        # If we fix the error and call construct_full_path() we will get T:\Vacation 

    except ValueError as error:
        print(error)
    else:
        print(portable_drive)
        print(vacation_pictures)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It may not be the best approach, but it works. I know a nested `for` loop is bad, but I don't see any other way to validate the individual characters of a `string`.

Comment: Change `_forbidden_characters` to a `set`,  and why the double `for` loop?: `for item in character:`

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse - You have have a list of subdirectories, and each subdirectory name could contain invalid characters.

Answer (score 0):

A `regex` solution:

```
import re

windows_path_regex = re.compile(r"""
\A
(?:(?:[a-z]:|\\\\[a-z0-9_.$\●-]+\\[a-z0-9_.$\●-]+)\\|  # Drive
   \\?[^\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\?)                           # Relative path
(?:[^\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\)*                              # Folder
[^\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]*                                     # File
\Z
""", re.VERBOSE|re.I)
d = windows_path_regex .match(r"\test\txt.txt")
print(bool(d))
```

Note that`\` is a valid path but `/` is not.

I used [8.18. Validate Windows Paths](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch08s18.html) as a reference.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) state that `isdir()` will test if the path is an existing directory. The directory in my example doesn't exist(yet). I want to ensure the string provide is valid for a directory name, it doesn't matter if it exists or not.

Comment: No problem. I've written my own answer as well, won't mind getting feedback. :D.

Comment: @nsonline Try that solution