# Regex to validate relative path with single / or ending with /

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to compose a regex which checks the validity of a relative path. It should start with a `/` and if it has anything following it, it must also end with another `/`.

Examples:

- `/` => valid
- `//` => not valid
- `/abc` => not valid
- `/abc/` => valid

I'm using the following at the moment which responds correctly for all cases except the single `/`: `"^\/[ A-Za-z0-9_\/]+\/"`

Do I need a lookahead?

Comment: Windows allows Unicode paths. Don't force me to use A-Z only. It can also contain spaces. What kind of path should this be? Part of a URL or Linux Path? Linux Paths can even contain (escaped) slashes, IMHO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check whether a path is valid in Python without creating a file at the path's target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532499/check-whether-a-path-is-valid-in-python-without-creating-a-file-at-the-paths-ta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following would work:

```
^\/(?:[^/\n]+\/)*$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uriYR8/1). You could match whichever characters you'd want to allow for inside the character class, but the above would mean:

- `^\/` - Start-line anchor and a escaped forward slash;
- `(?:[^/\n]+\/)*` - A non-capturing, 1+ negated characters '/' or a newline, followed by an escaped forward slash, matched 0+ times;
- `$` - End-line anchor.