# Make string safe for path specifically for the current os

Tags: python, path

I want to fix this function so that special characters are replaced with a similar legal character or in case that's too complex removed depending on the os.

Is there a simple way to do that or should I just do something like?

```
value = "".join(c for c in meta[key] if c.isalnum() or c in " -._")
value = " ".join(value.split())

def build_folder_tree(tree: str, meta: Dict) -> str:
    """
    Build a folder tree from a metadata dictionary
    """
    path = ""
    for key in tree.split(os.sep):
        if key not in meta or not meta[key]:
            continue
        value = meta[key]
        if isinstance(value, list):
            value = meta[key][0]
        path = os.path.join(path, value)
    return path
```

edit: I think I'll use pathvalidate package because it can check automatically for the current os.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check whether a path is valid in Python without creating a file at the path's target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532499/check-whether-a-path-is-valid-in-python-without-creating-a-file-at-the-paths-ta)

Comment: I want to make it valid, no need to check the validity.

Comment: The pathlib  is a good way to deal with path for different os's

Comment: I know, I'm using it, but I don't think it has an option to replace illegal characters.

Comment: try regex to parse your string before forward onto Pathlib