# How do I check if a String can be made into a valid directory

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a system where the user inputs a string which will be made into a directory. How would I check if the string is able to actually make the directory without error. So the user can't make " " directories, directories with `"/\:*?<>|"` in them, or any kind of directory that can't actually be made.

I've tried nothing as searching it up on stackoverflow or google returns with no results with what I am looking for.

Comment: What about putting the command that makes the folder inside a try? If it throws an exception then it means the name is invalid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check whether a path is valid in Python without creating a file at the path's target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532499/check-whether-a-path-is-valid-in-python-without-creating-a-file-at-the-paths-ta) Although try/except is the best approach

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki exactly that can be the only valid solution for that just check if the define specific character in try block and remaining if not match you can get to except block

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Get the user's input.
2. Check for invalid characters such as
   /:*?<>|.

```
import os

user_input = input("Enter a directory name: ")

# Function to check if a string is a valid directory name
def is_valid_directory_name(name):
    # List of invalid characters
    invalid_chars = r'\/:*?<>|'
    
    if any(char in invalid_chars for char in name) or name.isspace():
        return False
    return True

if is_valid_directory_name(user_input):
    try:
        # Create the directory
        os.mkdir(user_input)
        print(f"Directory '{user_input}' created successfully.")
    except FileExistsError:
        print(f"Directory '{user_input}' already exists.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while creating the directory: {e}")
else:
    print("Invalid directory name. Please avoid special characters and spaces.")
```

Comment: "Check for invalid characters such as /:*?<>| and spaces".  Spaces are not invalid characters for folders

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Yes that what i did in the same code

Comment: A directory with a single space and nothing else is not a valid directory though

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki A directory name that includes spaces is considered valid, but if it consists only of spaces, it will be considered invalid.

Comment: But this is not what your code checks. Your code said: check for invalid characters and spaces. My comment is that spaces are not invalid characters

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki only spaces for directory isn't invalid? Correct me if i am wrong please.